# "complete" as an intransitive verb?

Tags: transitivity, active-vs-passive

I came across this sentence somewhere:

> This dictionary took three years ***to complete***.

Clearly, it means '[...] took three years **to be completed**'.
Is this sentence correct? And if so, how can the use of non-passive voice be explained? I looked in several dictionaries but I couldn't find an intransitive form for 'complete'. Is 'complete' an ergative verb?
Which form is more common?

Comment: You should think of this sentence as being *This dictionary took three years for us/them/him to complete,* with *for us/them/him* left out.

Comment: @PeterShor Is this sort of omission/ellipsis common in English? It indeed sounds better with the 'for them' added. But I was mostly comparing the sentence to something like "It took us three years to complete the dictionary" where the 'subject' of the 'to complete' infinitive is clearly *us/we* and its object is *the dictionary*, at least based on the meaning. Whereas the infinitive in the original sentence doesn't appear to have a object. Please correct me if I'm wrong; I'm not sure about this grammatical structure.

Comment: Moreover, the fact that both passive and active voice appear to work in this sentence is confusing me. (Unless the passive form is wrong and I'm mistaken)

Comment: A similar sentence is *The game Monopoly requires infinite patience to play.* The passive voice doesn't work here: *The game Monopoly requires infinite patience to be played* is not anything a native speaker would say.

Comment: The object of the infinitive *to complete* in the original sentence is *dictionary.* Unfortunately, I don't know the technical term for this grammatical structure.

Comment: @PeterShor Would you say that the sentence *The phrase 'id est' requires translation to be understood* sounds unnatural to a native speaker? I don't quite understand the difference between your example and this one; and the alternative *The phrase 'id est' requires translation to understand* sounds strange to me, although I am not a native speaker and my intuition is not to be trusted.

Comment: You're right; *requires translation to be understood* sounds natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sentence

> This dictionary took three years to complete.

'To complete' is not functioning as an intransitive verb; rather, the structure used is a *nonfinite relative clause* with the logical subject of the sentence acting as the *object* of the infinitive clause, while the subject of the clause remains unspecified, forming a passive-like structure. Another example of such a construction is

> Cancer prevention is a common topic **to talk about** in these circles.

where the people *talking about* the topic is left unspecified, but the implied object of the clause is *cancer prevention*.